# is there any data to save which filter I choose in WINAPI - OPENFILENAME

Tags: c, winapi

I just want to know which filter user choose.

```
void LoadFilePath(char *_szFilePath, int _nFilePathSize)
{
   if( !_szFilePath) return;
    if( _nFilePathSize < MAX_PATH ) return;

    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char lpstrFile[MAX_PATH] = "";

    memset(&ofn, 0 ,sizeof(OPENFILENAME));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "VTX File(*.vtx)\0*.vtx\0";
    ofn.lpstrFile = lpstrFile;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = ".\\";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_NOCHANGEDIR;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;

    if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn) != 0 ){
        sprintf(_szFilePath,"%s",ofn.lpstrFile);
    }
    if(ofn.lpstrFile[0] == 0 )
    {
        printf("no selected file \n");
        system("pause()");
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

it is simple code to open file explorer and save path to second parameter.
filter is .vtx but i try to add more. then i want to which filter user chooses.
is there a good way ? thank you

Answer (score 7):

The [`OPENFILENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) structure contains a field `nFilterIndex`. This field is updated as the user interacts with the dialog. The relevant part of the documentation:

> When the user selects a file, nFilterIndex returns the index of the currently displayed filter.

If you want to be informed about changes as they happen (i.e. while the dialog is displayed) you have to set a hook procedure and handle the [`CDN_TYPECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646868.aspx) notification.